# Automatic Vertical Scrolling of Text in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I know that this is a very debated topic on this website and it has been asked many times before. But all the responses so far haven't been very helpful.

Essentially what i am trying to do, is create a textField, that contains information. Like a console in counter Strike for example. And i want to have a text entry box that allows for user entry. I would Like to be able to dynamically add lines of text to the above mentioned textbox, and i want it to scroll the the bottom. So the latest text entry or added text is always at the bottom. But i can still scroll up and go through the old entries.

So essentially exactly like the counter Strike console. Or any other game text consoles:

http://www.counter-strike-source-tips.com/images/counter-strike-source-binding.jpg

Here is an image  as an example ^^

Thank you so much. I've spent 2 days on this...

Here is what i have tried so far:

> Scroll View 
>   Text Scroll Vertical Bar

But nothing seems to automatically scroll down to the latest entry.

Here is my Bad XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shipName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Ship Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shipName" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upgrade2Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   Speed:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speedActual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shipDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shipName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/upgrade2Name"
            android:text="   Distance:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distanceActua"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shipDistance"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName"
            android:text="0" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shipLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shipName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shipDistance"
            android:text="   Location:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationActual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shipDistance"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName"
            android:text="Earth - Launch Station" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shipFuel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shipLocation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shipLocation"
            android:text="   Fuel:" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/fuelBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/statusActual"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shipStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shipFuel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shipFuel"
            android:text="   Status:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusActual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/data"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName"
            android:text="Ready for Launch" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shipStatus"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shipStatus"
            android:text="   Data:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vehicleInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/data"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/data"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName"
            android:text="0" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/researchPoints"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/data"
            android:layout_below="@+id/data"
            android:text="   Research Points:   " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vehicleMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vehicleInfo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipName"
            android:text="0" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/launchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/upgradeButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/upgradeButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Launch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upgradeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Upgrade" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsFeed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:text="newsfeed" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The newsFeed is supposed to be where the scrolling occurs:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsFeed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:text="newsfeed" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you again.

Comment: The newsFeed is supposed be the Console.

Comment: Simple implement a listview

Comment: So instead of textview i simply say listview? And then i can just add items to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

or

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView .getBottom());
```

Syntax:

```
public void scrollTo (int x, int y)
```

Set the scrolled position of your view. This will cause a call to onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) and the view will be invalidated.

Parameters:

x : the x position to scroll to

y : the y position to scroll to

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29